Can I reinstall Homebrew while keeping all my packages?
I had reinstalled Homebrew because I had trouble installing packages from taps. If I ever have to do so again I'd like to without removing my packages. Running the Homebrew uninstall script NONINTERACTIVE=1 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)" and then installing it again: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" deletes all my packages.

It’s not entirely clear why you’re uninstalling if you want to keep packages. Are you doing this as a troubleshooting step or could you edit in the overall problem you’re working to solve?

I added an edit: I had reinstalled Homebrew because I had trouble installing packages from taps. If I ever have to do so again I'd like to without removing my packages.

OK - that adds some excellent details - I wonder if installing brew on top of the existing files would be better first step next time you need to debug the tool. The brew doctor and other troubleshooting steps will be helpful if you have a cask issue going forward. Hopefully you get things sorted quickly

If bmike's excellent recommendation to run brew doctor doesn't help, can you refocus the question on the actual problem you have with a specific tap? There might be easier solutions than reinstalling everything.

I had already reinstalled homebrew. I had tried brew doctor but it didn't report any issues. I had asked for help in the Homebrew GH discussions and reinstalling seemed like the best course of action.

If you want to remove Homebrew, and then reinstall it, save your installed packages first.
Use the command brew bundle dump to create a Brewfile listing your installed packages, and brew bundle to reinstall them.
(ref: https://openfolder.sh/macos-migrations-with-brewfile and https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage)
